# Make a Chrome Extension Private

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension, but no Google Business account, that I would like to keep private and share only with a few people.  As of early 2014 Google no longer allows extensions that are not in the Chrome Store (outside of Developer Mode).  Since Developer Mode is not really an option (some of these users are not very literate technically), Developer mode is really not an option for me.  Is there a way to still have a private Chrome store or Extension in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When publishing an extension you can select to make it private and choose a Google Group whose members you want to have access. Anyone who is a member of the Google Group can see and install the extension when they are signed into the Web Store.

[image]